# Measuring non-Cauchyness of sequences on $c_{0}$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in the closed unit ball $B_{c_{0}}$ of $c_{0}$. Let $\epsilon>0$. My question: Is there a subsequence $(z_{n})_{n}$ of $(x_{n})_{n}$ so that $\textrm{ca}((z_{n})_{n})\leq 1+\epsilon$ ? where $\textrm{ca}((z_{n})_{n})=\inf\limits_{n}\sup\limits_{k,l\geq n}\|z_{k}-z_{l}\|.$

Thank you.

Comment: Let $x_n=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,...)$ with the $-1$ in the $n$th position. Then $\|x_n-x_m\|=2$ for any $m\ne n$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas   Thanks, Anthony. You are right.!